# Create Magento category with assigned id using SOAP api

Tags: api, magento, soap

I am working on a script (which is in Python) for doing some management on our Magento environment.
Now I am wondering if I can create categories **with** assigned ID.
I think this might be impossible due to key constraints. But is there a way?
Just putting `category_id` in the parameter list in `catalog_category.create`, it does not work, it just skips the parameter.
The main reason of wanting this is because I need to know the category ID in order to create the subcategories.
I do know the Magento API returns the ID of the created category. 
But, I have no way of knowing what subcategories are supposed to go to that created category.
 (Or I can rewrite a load of code, which I am not too fond of...).
So I was thinking this was the easiest way to go with right now.
Any suggestions, comments, answers? Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Magento's entity IDs are for Magento so you cannot specify what you'd like them to be.

When you create an entity with the API it will return the new ID, as you've said.

For your use case it might be easiest to add a new attribute to your categories in Magento, call it "my_category_id" or something and allow your API to set that instead.

Comment: Alright, I might add the new category id attribute. Although, this might be a hussle as well, because the api requires you to specify the actual id, not the custom attribute id. Eitherway, thank you very much for the info!

Comment: No problem. You can always extend the API resource class and adjust it slightly